# Java FlowLayout inside FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I am trying to design similar to a browsers title bar(top of the browser). Left side has tabs and  right side has minimize, resize(minimize/maximize),exit button.

For this I tried like.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
JPanel tabpanel= new JPanel();
tabpanel.setLayout(new  FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
tabpanel.add(new JButton("Tab 1"));
tabpanel.add(new JButton("Tab 2"));
panel.add(tabpanel); 
panel.add(new JButton("Minimize")); 
panel.add(new JButton("Resize")); 
panel.add(new JButton("Quit"));
```

Created Quit, Resize, Minimize buttons at the right as my needed but tabs created near Minimize button not LEFT of Frame. I think there should be method or anything to fill it remainng content or should I use another layout? Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm just going to say it - `GridBagLayout`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Heresy!!!! ;-) (Seriously, the `GridBagLayout` is famous for being [somewhat awkward to use](https://youtu.be/UuLaxbFKAcc) ). From the description, it sounds like it could be solved with putting a `BorderLayout` into the title bar and placing the two panels with the buttons into the `EAST` and `WEST`. @Tekin If you think that could solve the issue, I'd write this as an answer including a [MCVE])

Comment: When posting the MCVE suggested by @Marco13: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: @Marco13 `GridBagLayout` is the most flexible layout manager available, with it comes complexity. It would solve the issue the OP is describing very simply, within a single container

Comment: @Marco13 There you go, solved in 9 lines of code 

Comment: I have decided using Gridbaglayout But issue is that I cannot know the mechanism of it. Afterwards a lot of research I have found this link maybe helpful https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gbcustomizer-basic.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend `GridBagLayout`, it's one of the most flexible and configurable layout managers available, but it does bring with it complexity

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
public class HeaderPane extends JPanel {

    public HeaderPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        add(new JButton("Tab 1"));
        add(new JButton("Tab 2"));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_TRAILING;

        add(new JButton("Minimize"), gbc);
        add(new JButton("Maximise"));
        add(new JButton("Close"));          
    }

}
```

Arrgggh, the complexity burns, it burns  *sarcasm*

So, this solution is a single container, with a single layout manager.  I'm not saying a more complex requirement might benefit from a compounding solution (I'd be tempted to put the min/max/close and tab buttons in there own containers), but as a starting point, it's relatively simple.

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new HeaderPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new JPanel() { 
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(600, 200);
                    }                   
                });
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class HeaderPane extends JPanel {

        public HeaderPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add(new JButton("Tab 1"));
            add(new JButton("Tab 2"));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_TRAILING;

            add(new JButton("Minimize"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Maximise"));
            add(new JButton("Close"));          
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: (1+) Learned a couple of things with this example:1) if you don't specify constraints you get a "flow layout" 2) I didn't know layout managers worked differently in Mac vs Windows. In this example and in the BoxLayout example by Hao on Windows there is no spacing between components. I thought it was the job of the layout manager to control spacing. Does Mac override this somehow to make sure there is a gap between components? I would have thought you need to use the "insets" constraint to get a gap between components.

Comment: @camickr i think it’s down to how the buttons work - mac buttons have additional insets for focus border

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually All of aproaches have solved my problem but I decided using Gridbaglayout but I could not understand How did Gridbaglayout did. GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_TRAILING is the key but I could not get it.Is there a good explain to understand?

Comment: @TekinGüllü [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) would be good place to start. The `anchor` property just tells the layout where in the cell the components want to be placed, the `BASELINE_TRAILING` means hat the component should be horizontally placed along the trailing edge.  The "trailing edge" has different meanings for left-to-right and right-to-left languages

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `BoxLayout` as the layout manager of `panel` to organize the left and right part.

Full demo code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Solution");
            JPanel container = new JPanel();
            container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
            JPanel tabpanel= new JPanel();
            tabpanel.setLayout(new  FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            tabpanel.add(new JButton("Tab 1"));
            tabpanel.add(new JButton("Tab 2"));
            panel.add(tabpanel);
            panel.add(new JButton("Minimize"));
            panel.add(new JButton("Resize"));
            panel.add(new JButton("Quit"));

            container.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            frame.add(container);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

What it looks like:

[image]

Comment: (1+) but, as far as I know a BoxLayout does not automatically add spacing between components. When I run your code on Windows, the Minimize/Resize/Quit buttons have no spacing and you need to add Box.createHorizontalStrut(5) between the components to get the same 5 pixel spacing you get by default with the FlowLayout. Using a BoxLayout you also don't need the tabPanel. You just add the buttons and then use Box.addHorizontalGlue() after the second tab button. See the Swing tutorial on [Using Invisible Components as Filler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments: One solution could be to place the "tabs" and "buttons" into separate panels, and add them in the `WEST` and `EAST` of the title panel, which has a `BorderLayout`:

[image: Title bar layout]

Here is the MCVE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TitleBarLayout
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel titleBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel();
        tabPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tabPanel.add(new JButton("Tab 1"));
        tabPanel.add(new JButton("Tab 2"));
        titleBar.add(tabPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("Minimize"));
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("Resize"));
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("Quit"));
        titleBar.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        mainPanel.add(titleBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        f.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```