# Unexpected behavior of FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, flowlayout

I'm using `JPanel` with a default `FlowLayout` layout manager. I think in case the application window was resized and there is not enough width to show all components in `JPanel` in one row, some components will be moved to another row(s).

This assumption is based on the documentation:

> If the horizontal space in the container is too small to put all the components in one row, the FlowLayout class uses multiple rows.

*https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html*

It works in some cases. For example, while using this code and decreasing window width, buttons will be located on different rows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FlowLayoutExpected {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");

        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button3);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);

        frame.setSize(350, 70);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Before decreasing width
[image] -> After decreasing width
[image]

But it is enough to put one `JPanel` into another `JPanel` and layout manager stops to behave as expected:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FlowLayoutReal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");

        innerPanel.add(button1);
        innerPanel.add(button2);
        innerPanel.add(button3);

        outerPanel.add(innerPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, outerPanel);

        frame.setSize(350, 70);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Before decreasing width
[image] -> After decreasing width
[image]

I'm trying to clarify what I misunderstood.

---

I've read a lot of suggestions to use [WrapLayout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) instead of `FlowLayout`. It seems reasonable, but still not clear for me why I got inconsistent behavior in the examples above.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234113/java-flowlayout-inside-flowlayout ... point is: your expectation is flawed. You cant expect to "simply" push panels inside panels like that. All these layout managers have certain "properties" and use cases, and "flow inside flow" isnt necessarily a supported use case. In other words: if you need more complicated UIs, then you get there by using the more complicated layout managers, not by pulling together the simple ones.

Comment: @GhostCat, yeah, I see what you mean. I will use other layout managers for complicated UIs. I've provided a simplified example and I'm not going to put JPanel on JPanel without a reason :-)
At the same time, I can't find any statements in the docs or somewhere else why I can't do that.
So my intension is to understand what I missed in the documentation, to avoid such issues (with other docs as well) in the future.

Comment: "I can't find any statements in the docs or somewhere else why I can't do that."  The code is the ultimate documentation.  Make a note that you can't put a FlowLayout inside of a FlowLayout inside of a BorderLayout in your developer's notebook and move on to the next problem.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, "The code is the ultimate documentation." - simple, but yet helpful reminder. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
```

First of all that method has been "obsolete" since JDK1.1.

The preferred approach since then is to add the "constraint" as the second parameter:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

> But it is enough to put one JPanel into another JPanel and layout manager stops to behave as expected:

The code is working as expected. The issue is your expectation.

Change the code in your first example:

```
//frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Now, when you decrease the width the components disappear. This is because the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` will respect the preferred height of the component added. The preferred height is determined by displaying all components on a single row.

> But it is enough to put one JPanel into another JPanel and layout manager stops to behave as expected

When you start wrapping panels you need to understand the implications.

The `FlowLayout` respects the preferred size of all components added. So the components in the inner panel are all displayed in a row as expected.

When you add the outer panel to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` the outer panel size is adjusted, but it does not affect the inner panel because the rules of the `FlowLayout`, say any component added is displayed at the top of the panel. Since the inner panel is a single component, there is nothing to wrap.

This is a trick that is often used to your advantage to ensure a component retains its preferred size.

Another example. Maybe you have a horizontal `GridLayout` of buttons on a panel you want to add to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`.

If you add the panel directly, then the size of the button will shrink/grow as the frame with is changed.

If you want the buttons size to remain constant, you can use a "wrapper" panel. Then the "wrapper" panel size shrinks/grows, but the buttons size remains constant.

You need to understand the rules of the layout manager so you can use it effectively.

Comment: camickr, thank you for the great explanation. The issue is clear for me now. Honestly, at first, I didn't get why the inner panel isn't resizing while changing the window size (like the outer panel is), but later on, I checked the difference in layoutContainer() methods in FlowLayout and BorderLayout and now I see the reason.